# How to change static resources path for Vue App?

Tags: vue.js, babeljs

when building a Vue app, a "dist" folder will be created, with index.html and folders like js and css.
Is it possible to configure that everything except the index.html is a folder deeper, and the references to them in the index.html are also changed accordingly?

The reason I want to to this, is because I have 2 vue apps running on different ports. Above them, there is a proxy that forwards request to the respective application, and this is done by url matching.
So if the URL contains "foo" the request is forwarded to the 8080 port, else to the 8081.
The problem is, when the "foo" Vue app tries to load it's resources, it's requests do not contain "foo", therefor they will go to the wrong application.

Edit:
A little bit more explanation

```js
  if(req.url.includes("/foo/")){
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' });
  } else {
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8081' });
  }
```

On the two ports two different vue apps run. But when the one running on 8080 requests it's static resources, those requests do not contain "foo", and those requests will be redirected to 8081.
That is why I want those requests to contain foo.

Comment: You likely have XY problem that should be solved in another way. These foo, etc are still connected because they have common chunks. If they are independent apps, there probably should be independent builds.

Comment: They have independent builds. They are entirely different vue apps.

Comment: Then I don't understand the problem you describe. Usually there will be /foo/index.html, /foo/assets/js/..., etc, so dist folder structure stays the same for all apps. Any way, if you use Vue CLI (the question doesn't say this,), assets path can be configured with ` assetsDir`.

Comment: That solved it indeed, thank you very much.